# How to add a facebook-like button in a responsive website?

Tags: facebook-like

I am working on a new version of our website, based on a commercial framework (Aspdotnetstorefront) with a responsive template.

We have a few pages where we want to include a Facebook "like button". I tried to use the same code we have in our current site in the new responsive version but it's ruining the design (its width disregards the limit of the device screen size and so the contents of the whole page is cut).

The code we have is the one auto generated by the Facebook developers page (it creates a class called 'fb-root').

I checked the Facebook developers page and the solution they offer is still the old one I have, or in other words, completely useless.

I would like to know if there is any available version that WORKS.

Thank you!

PS: This "facebook like button" RIGHT BELOW is exactly what I need as it seems to work very responsively.

Comment: there is no like button "right below"...? anyway, can you show at least a screenshot about what it looks like, and explain in detail how you want it to look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see a way of show a screenshot. There is not any way of upload a picture that I can know of. Thank you!